# eclipse field editor for password

Tags: eclipse, jface

I have a preferences page that has some StringFieldEditor to hold different values. One of them is meant for password. I want the password to be displayed as asterisk or some other special character. I have to use org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditor or any of its subclass only. Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
password = new StringFieldEditor("passwd", "Password", getFieldEditorParent()) {

@Override
    protected void doFillIntoGrid(Composite parent, int numColumns) {
        super.doFillIntoGrid(parent, numColumns);

        getTextControl().setEchoChar('*');
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringFieldEditor passwordField = new StringFieldEditor("password", "Password", getFieldEditorParent());
passwordField.getTextControl(getFieldEditorParent()).setEchoChar('*');

addField(passwordField);
```